How do string variables work within if statements?
I'm getting errors (in java) regarding a string variable. I'm trying to make sure that I can take the user's input (which is a string) and if its Y (meaning yes) then I'll add the computer (basic) to the total cost. I really need to know what wrong with my code as I want to add more code such as asking the user whether they want antivirus software which will increase the cost if they say yes. I also want to add a statement in case they say N (meaning no). Here is the code
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Order {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double basic, screen, lscreen, antivirus, printer, totalcost;
    String userinput;
    basic = 375.99;
    System.out.print("The basic system costs £375.99. Do you want it? Y/N");
    userinput = keyboard.next();
    if (userinput == Y)
        {
        totalcost = basic + totalcost
        }
    
}

}
I think I've already said enough. To be clear the line with 'if (userinput == Y)' and the line 'totalcost = basic + totalcost' are both having the red squiggily line indicating error.

Hello Michael, welcome, change the declaration totalcost; to totalcost = 0.0, and if( userinput == Y ) to if( userinput.equals( "Y" )).

BTW totalcost = basic + totalcost is often easier to understand when written as totalcost += basic; (and there is missing a semi-colon ; after the original statement); Also be aware of the difference between Double and double, for calculations, you mostly will need double
